# Filling sections (specific rows/columns) of dataframe based on criteria (corresponding to df1 row/column names) defined another df

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to help a df of schedules for our team.

I have a set of "givens" in the form of a df that contains: 1) name, 2) "effective dates" (start/stop) for a given person/schedule and 3) True/False values for each day of the week.

My destination is a date-indexed df with columns for each person, which I'd like to populate with True (or 1) for each day that falls between the effective dates of the person/schedule AND whose day_name is marked 'True' in the "givens".

Sample "givens" dataframe:

```
        Start      | End        | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | [etc.]
bruna | 2020-07-31 | 2020-09-30 | True   | True   | False   | True      | (etc.)
jane  | 2020-07-31 | 2020-10-31 | False  | True   | True    | True      | (etc.)
...
bruna | 2020-10-01 | 2020-11-15 | True   | True   | True    | False     | (etc.)
```

And "destination" dataframe:

```
                          bruna     | jane   
2020-01-01   Wednesday    NaN       | NaN
...
2020-09-27   Sunday       NaN       | NaN
2020-09-28   Monday       NaN       | NaN
...
2020-10-07   Wednesday    NaN       | NaN
...
```

Desired outcome:

```
                          bruna     | jane   
2020-01-01   Wednesday    NaN       | NaN (NaN if no dates represented in schedules
...
2020-09-27   Sunday       True      | False 
2020-09-28   Monday       True      | True
2020-09-29   Tuesday      False     | True   
2020-09-30   Wednesday    True      | True
...
2020-10-04   Sunday       True      | False 
2020-10-05   Monday       True      | True
2020-10-06   Tuesday      **True**      | True 
2020-10-07   Wednesday    **False**     | True
...
```

I'll be doing this for up to ~100 people.

I've been thinking about this a bit, but am just not proficient enough to come up with a good solution. Appreciate any direction, hints, or ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more efficient approach, but we used the following process flow to create it.

1. Replicate the number of days from the start date to the end date + 1, line by line, in an empty data frame. Merge them together.
2. Add the cumulative sum of each name to the combined data frame. (This will be the index to be combined later.)
3. Create another data frame (name, date and day of the week) using a similar technique.
4. Add the cumulative sum of the name units in the same way.
5. Combine the two data frames you created.
6. Add a new status column and get the values for each day of the week column against the values for the day of the week column.
7. Add only the columns we need and format them with the pivot function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
name      Start       End      Sunday  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
bruna  2020-07-31  2020-09-30  True    True    False    True True True True
jane   2020-07-31  2020-10-31  False   True    True     True True True True
bruna  2020-10-01  2020-11-15  True    True    True     False True True True
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df[['Start','End']] = df[['Start','End']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df_all = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df)):
    tmp = pd.DataFrame([df.loc[i]]*((df.loc[i,'End']-df.loc[i,'Start']).days+1))
    df_all = df_all.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)
df_all['flg'] = df_all.groupby('name').cumcount()
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df)):
    tmp_rng = pd.date_range(df.loc[i,'Start'], df.loc[i,'End'], freq='1D')
    name = df.loc[i,'name']
    num = len(tmp_rng)
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'name':[name]*num, 'date':tmp_rng})
    df2 = df2.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)
df2['flg'] = df2.groupby('name').cumcount()
df2['weekday'] = df2['date'].dt.strftime('%A')
df2 = df2.merge(df_all, on=['name','flg'], how='inner')
df2['status'] = ''
for k in range(len(df2)):
    df2.loc[k, 'status'] = df2.loc[k, df2.loc[k, 'weekday']]
df2 = df2[['name','weekday', 'date','status']]
df2 = pd.pivot(df2, index=['date','weekday'], columns='name', values='status')
df2.tail(10)
             name   bruna   jane
    date    weekday     
2020-11-06  Friday  True    NaN
2020-11-07  Saturday    True    NaN
2020-11-08  Sunday  True    NaN
2020-11-09  Monday  True    NaN
2020-11-10  Tuesday True    NaN
2020-11-11  Wednesday   False   NaN
2020-11-12  Thursday    True    NaN
2020-11-13  Friday  True    NaN
2020-11-14  Saturday    True    NaN
2020-11-15  Sunday  True    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll play around with it today or tomorrow and come back to edit this comment.

Comment: Yes! Thanks so much for your help.